# redirect too many times laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I try to use redirect->action It error too many redirect  in my Controller

```
try {
  //If check urL category null
  if (is_null($category)){
      Log::error("[Front] MenuController@menu : notfound public category ");

      //error redirect
       return redirect()->action('Front\HomeSlideviewController@index', $url);
  }
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    return 'error';
}
```

here is my web.php

```
  Route::get('/{url?}', 'MenuController@menu');
  Route::get('/{name?}', 'HomeSlideviewController@index')->name('promotiondetail');
```

I try to make a fucntion if Url is empty use redirect action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your routes are identical and only the first one is matched.

Please note that, when redirecting to action, Laravel is resolving your action to route anyway, so it is the same as redirecting to route name (which is more bulletproof). By the way, the second parameter should be an array.

```
return redirect()->action('Front\HomeSlideviewController@index', $url);
```

To do what you want, you need one `catchAll` action and return different responses based on your logic:

```
/**
 * @param $string
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
 */
public function catchAllAction($string)
{
    $page = Page::whereHas('translations', function ($query) use ($string) {
        $query->where('locale', App::getLocale())->where('slug', $string);
    })->first();

    if ($page) {
        return $this->showPage($page);
    }

    $news = News::whereHas('translations', function ($query) use ($string) {
        $query->where('locale', App::getLocale())->where('slug', $string);
    })->first();

    if ($news) {
        return $this->showSingleNews($news);
    }

    throw new NotFoundHttpException('This page does not exist');
}
```

Comment: is their any way if empty route 1  catch redirect to route 2 ?

Comment: so It will same as like `redirect()->route('promotiondetail',$url);` right ?

Comment: Instead of creating two routes and redirections, you need just one and return different responses, please check my updated answer:)

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what's ShowPage() , showsingleNews()  is that a function ?

Comment: `public function showPage(Page $page)
    {
        return view('pages/static-page', [
            'page' => $page
        ]);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You have route conflict, it will call first route every time.
try to change your route.

Comment: can you give me some example pleae

Comment: Something like  `Route::get('/{url?}', 'MenuController@menu');
  Route::get('/home/{name?}', 'HomeSlideviewController@index')->name('promotiondetail');`

Comment: well I know how to do something like this thank but is thier anyway to remove/home/ ?